# I'm getting two errors whilst following this tutorial and I'm not very sure how to fix it (I'm a beginner)

Tags: python

I was following a tutorial but kept receiving two errors once I reached a certain part. The errors were:

```
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
    if score is > high_score:
            ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The piece of code below is what included the errors

```
 score += 1
 if score is > high_score:
        high_score = score
```

The error shown:

```
pen.write("Score:  {}  High Score:  {}".format(score, high_score), align="center"), font=("College", 24, "bold"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if score > high_score:
    high_score = score
    pen.write("Score:  {}  High Score:  {}".format(score, high_score),
            align="center", font=("College", 24, "bold"))
```

There are two errors, first there must not be `is` after score and second bracket must not be closed after center.

Answer (score 1):

"is" is unnecessary in if statement.
The correct is

```
if score > high_score:
        high_score = score
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
if score > high_score:
        high_score = score

pen.write("Score:  {}  High Score:  {}".format(score, high_score), align="center", font=("College", 24, "bold"))
```

You should remove 'is' from the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if score > high_score:
    **statement
```

removing 'is' from the condition will do the work hopefully.